# "Delete Permanently" instead of "Move to Trash" in '/var/www/html' Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, apache2, php, lamp, trash

After successful installation of LAMP from this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04), everything works fine but when I tried to delete some files, it shows me **Delete Permanently** option instead of **Move to Trash**.

If I put the same file in my **Home** folder, it moved to trash successfully but not the files which are in `/var/www/html` folder.

Can anyone help me please, I am stuck for many days?